# How can you make the content of a ListBoxItem copyable?

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

How can you make the content of a ListBoxItem copyable? not editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a contextmenu, a button or keybinding(Ctrl+C)

If you've your ListBoxItem content ready in your viewmodel then in the command initiated by one of the above say

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)contentOfListBoxItem);
```

This would copy the contentOfListBoxItem to clipboard

Comment: And if you run into an error right away, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666/clipbrd-e-cant-open-error-when-setting-the-clipboard-from-net.