# GetDataObject Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed 0x800401D0

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, clipboard, excel-addins

I made an AddIn for Excel (2016), that saves the print area as a jpg file. It worked fine for a few months. Nowadays I get more and more error reports from users, all get the same error (picture below). The users have Windows 7 with Excel 2013 or Windows 10 with Excel 2016, both have this error. At the first times reinstall of my program helped, but from now it doesn't help.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public static void Save(string report, string area, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Window window = e.Control.Context;
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)window.Application.ActiveSheet);
    Excel.Range range = sheet.Range[sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea];

    range.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlPrinter, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture);
    range.Copy(Type.Missing);

    string fileName = @"\\server.company.lan\report.jpg";

    if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
    {
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        image.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running that on a non-STA thread? (PS: the type of Exception could seriously help...) also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666/clipbrd-e-cant-open-error-when-setting-the-clipboard-from-net

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I'm running that on a non-STA thread. I attached the error message to my question, that's all I have, due I can't reproduce this error on my computer.

Comment: You must use an STA thread to access the clipboard.

Comment: @SimonMourier It works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All clipboard access must run using an STA thread. There are many ways to do this:

- use [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) functions (Winforms or [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)) that guarantee the code runs on the UI thread (which should be STA)
- start your own Thread instance and use [SetAparmentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx)(STA),
- etc.